# Setting different interlinespace for body and footnote in ConTeXt

Tags: footnotes, context

I am trying ConTeXt and using grid layout `\setuplayout[grid=yes]`. I use these setup for body font, size and interlinespace: `\setupinterlinespace[line=14pt]` and `\setupbodyfont [Utopia Std,rm,12pt]`.

I followed ConTeXt's wiki to change interlinespace of footnote:

```
\startsetups[footnote:interlinespace]
  \setupinterlinespace[line=2.8ex]
\stopsetups

\setupnote[footnote][setups=footnote:interlinespace]
```

but my footnote still follows interlinespace of body.

I searched around and found an old hack by Wolfgang on mailing list.

```
\def\setnotebodyfont
   {\let\setnotebodyfont\relax
    \restoreglobalbodyfont
    \switchtobodyfont[\noteparameter\c!bodyfont]%
    \setuptolerance[\noteparameter\c!tolerance]%
    \setupalign[\noteparameter\c!align]%
    \noteparameter\c!commands} % <- new
```

and

```
\startsetups footnote:interlinespace
\setupinterlinespace[line=11pt]
\stopsetups

\setupnote
   [footnote]
   [bodyfont=9pt,
    commands=\directsetup{footnote:interlinespace}]
```

With no result as well. Please help.

Comment: To be fair, you won't see much of a difference between the text and the footnote with your current setting, because `2.8ex = 14.4816pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce.  This works as intended.

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\setupinterlinespace[line=5ex]

\startsetups[footnote:interlinespace]
  \setupinterlinespace[line=2.5ex]
\stopsetups

\setupnote[footnote][setups=footnote:interlinespace]

\starttext

\input knuth\footnote{\input knuth }

\stoptext
```

[image]